# Audio clicks / cracklings with ffmpeg audio recording on mac os

Tags: macos, audio, ffmpeg, recording

I'm having audio clicks on my ffmpeg audio recordings. If I record with OBS for example, the audio comes out just fine. This is what I put in the terminal:

```
ffmpeg -f avfoundation -i ":0" test.mp3
```

where 0 is my Soundflower audio device, which I found using `ffmpeg -f avfoundation -list_devices true -i ""`, which returns:

```
AVFoundation audio devices:
[0] Soundflower (2ch)
```

Soundflower, my speakers, and the ffmpeg recording are all set at 48kHz.
There is [another thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65817212/crackling-sound-when-recording-audio-with-ffmpeg) that states that this may be an issue with ffmpeg version 4.3, and to try to downgrade to 4.2; I tried to google how to downgrade on brew, but didn't find anything.

Comment: Same here. I've seen answers considering bit depth change from 24bit to 16bit but it didn't help for me. As of brew you can only downgrade to ffmpeg@2.8 which is very old. But you can try it. I didn't.

Answer (score 2):

Had same issue and downgrading to 4.2 did in fact fix the crackling.

You can grab a prebuilt 4.2 Mac binary from https://evermeet.cx/pub/ffmpeg/ffmpeg-4.2.3.zip (it's linked from https://ffmpeg.org/download.html#build-mac)